# ¿Cómo puedo incluir el número del cluster generado por el algoritmo de clusterización?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

Éste código, me genera las distancias y el clustering jerárquico con los 5 cluster que he pasado como parámetro, se pinta el dendograma, pero quiero que el número del cluster, aparezca en el dataset a nivel registro con un campo que se llame número del cluster.

Cuál es esa línea de código?

```
foodclust<-hclust(dist(food_norm[,c(2,4)]), method="ward.D")
plot(foodclust, labels=food_norm$Food)
rect.hclust(foodclust, 5)
```

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Bienvenidx. Por favor, [edit] tu pregunta y tradúcela, TODA, a español. Incluyendo el título. Gracias!

Comment: ok, cambiado gracias por el aviso

Answer (score 0):

Lo tengo.

La función `cutree` me da el número del cluster asignado

```
 cl <- cutree(foodclust, k = 5)
```

y con un `cbind`, puedo añadir el cluster al dataset.